# Spring Custom Configuration not populating properties with underscore

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to populate Custom class with properties. following is my Custom Properties class:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.bar")
public class CustomProperties{

    private String PROPERTY_ONE;

    private String propertyTwo;

    //setters 
    //getters
}
```

and my properties in `application.properties` are:

```
foo.bar.PROPERTY_ONE=some text
foo.bar.PROPERTY_TWO=some other text
```

When I am trying to use value from `CustomProperties` this is what I gets:

```
customProperties.getPROPERTY_ONE() = null
customProperties.getPopertyTwo() = some other text
```

So I observed that if I have variable name with underscore(_) in it not populating the property value.

is there any way to get the value with variable having underscore?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is 100% possible to get your configuration values.

It's all about the casing! Inside of `CustomProperties` simply name your first property `propertyOne` ... and refactor your getters/setters appropriately ... and you'll be good to go!

Spring's got the camel casing going on when translating the configuration fields to your Configuration classes/properties. So instead of matching the casing of your properties, follow the camel casing equivalent of the property name found in your configuration file.

Example: `PROPERTY_ONE` translates to `propertyOne`

Comment: So it means _its possible only with refactoring._ I was looking for an option skipping refactoring.

Comment: You can use the @Value annotation on the property `PROPERTY_TWO`. However, I believe it would require the full path to the property (including the prefix `foo.bar`).