# Spring boot 2.7 not reading application.properties using @Value annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to read some properties in the `application.properties` file from a non controller class.
According to the official Spring documentation every class annotated with @Component should be able to access those properties but i fail to do so.
This works fine in the controller but not in another class which is not a controller but is annotated with @Component

```
@Component
public class BitBucket {
    
      private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BitBucket.class);
      @Value("${app.bitbucket_username}")
      private String bitBucketUsername;
      @Value("${app.bitbucket_password}")
      private String bitBucketPassword;
      private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
      public BitBucket() {
        this.restTemplate = createRestTemplate();
      }
    
      private RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
        var builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        logger.info("The user is " + bitBucketUsername);
        logger.info("The pw is " + bitBucketPassword);
        return builder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .basicAuthentication(username, password)
            .build();
      }
    }
```

My application.properties file:

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=app-name
app.bitbucket_username=test
app.bitbucket_password=test
```

BTW i instantiate the BitBucket object with
`var bitBucket = new BitBucket();`
So it is not Autowired.

The printed logs are always null while i am expencting to see 'test', i really cant figure out what i am doing wrong.
I use Spring Boot 2.7 and Java 11

Comment: How is the BitBucket component you designed instantiated in your application? If it is "newed", then @Value injection won't work.

Comment: @ArthurNoseda yes i instantiate it with `new` keyword. Is not allowed?

Comment: Yes, with "New" the instance is no longer a spring managed component and @value will be null. See this https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class

Comment: It is about casing!
[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608067/spring-custom-configuration-not-populating-properties-with-underscore)